# Convergence of a Dirichlet series from divisors function and Ramanujan zeta identity

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, divisor-sum, dirichlet-series

I am trying to prove the following identity:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sigma_a(n)\sigma_b(n)}{n^s}
= \frac{\zeta(s)\zeta(s-a)\zeta(s-b)\zeta(s-a-b)}{\zeta(2s-a-b)}, \qquad
(\Re s > 1+\Re (a+b), \Re (a) \geq 0,\Re(b) \geq 0)
$$
If we assume that the sum on the left is convergent, this can be proved by first assuming $\Re(a),\Re(b) \neq 0$ and then taking a limit from the right.

However, how to prove that the sum on the left is convergent under these conditions without using more advanced results such as Gronwall's theorem? It suffices to show that $\sigma_a(n)$ grows asymptotically slower than $n^{\Re(a)}$, since from which we can bound the left side by a p-series.

Comment: $\sigma_a(n)\sigma_b(n)$ is multiplicative and it is immediate the Euler product of the LHS converges absolutely, thus the LHS converges absolutely. You should say faster not slower. For $\Re(a) \ge 0$, $\sigma_a(n)\le \tau(n) n^{\Re(a)}$  so the absolute convergence reduces to $\tau(n) = O(n^{\epsilon})$ which follows from  $m\le n!\implies \tau(m) \le 2^n$.